# How to Parse Strings from an ArrayList<>() into a Map<String, String>

Tags: java, lambda, split, hashmap, java-stream

I have a method that takes a parameter of filters that is an  ArrayList<>() of strings that I need to split on ":" and put in a map.

```
List<String> filtersQuery = new ArrayList<>();
        filtersQuery.add("brand:nike,adidas");
        filtersQuery.add("catagory:running");
```

And would like the output of the map to be:

```
brand=nike,adidas
catagory=running
```

I am currently trying to use stream(). Im new to Java and running into issues with getting it to parse correctly.

Comment: What is the full code you are trying to use? Would [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> filtersQuery = new ArrayList<>();
        filtersQuery.add("brand:nike,adidas");
        filtersQuery.add("category:running");

Map<String, String> filtersMap = filtersQuery
                .stream()
                .map(k -> k.split(":"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0],
                        a -> a[1]));
```

This give you better performance than @cheng gen answer

Comment: Ahh! This is what I was looking to achieve but went wrong my lambdas in toMap(). Thank you!

Comment: This code will throw an exception if the key is duplicated.

Comment: @ﾓｷｬﾃﾞ correct, we can add more param to toMap(). Like toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1], (a, b) ->b)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> filtersQuery = new ArrayList<>();
        filtersQuery.add("brand:nike,adidas");
        filtersQuery.add("category:running");

        Map<String, String> filtersMap = filtersQuery
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.split(":")[0],
                        v -> v.split(":")[1]));

        System.out.println(filtersMap);
```

It works.

Comment: @SoT, his answer is better than mine. I have realized the perfomance flaw, howerver, I dont know how to adjust it.